# MySQL Column is null, but not showing on SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I have a products table, reduced down to the relevent columns is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name',
  `teachingID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Teaching',
  `typeID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Product Type',
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

(I dont know how to draw the tables out nicely like I see some people do)

And so, I have a product in the table called `Business Cards`.  it has a `teachingID` of `NULL`, and a typeID of `22`.  But if I run:

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE teachingID <> 70 AND typeID = 22`

I get zero results.

There are two products in the table with the `typeID` of 22, one of them has the `teachingID` of 70.  The other has the `teachingID` of `NULL`

If I remove the `teachingID <> 70` part, Of course I get the two products.  Why is comparing `NULL != 70` failing?  Surely `NULL` does not equal 70?

Comment: `<> 70` is not the same as `IS NULL` Relational databases tend to treat NULL as a special case

Comment: This is 'nicely'

Comment: I think you should read [this](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/). It explains what exactly is NULL and how you can avoid such results in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what u were expecting but i will write the solutions that will happen in all cases.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE teachingID= 70 ANDtypeID= 22
```

This gives u the 70 item

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE teachingID <> 70 ANDtypeID= 22
```

This teoricaly should give u all the none 70 items, in other words the only one u have, the null. However it may only work for numerics and since null inst a number it wont count. To test this i would recomend for u to add another row in the table.

Comment: I didn't write `NULL != 70`, and you're right that doesnt make any sense.

Comment: Ye ye i notice and changed, just create a new row and give some value diferent then 70 and see that what i wrote was right.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is comparing NULL != 70 failing?

That's cause you can't compare `NULL` with equality operator; not only with some other value(s) but also with `NULL` and that's why there exists `IS NULL` operator and thus you should check your condition for nulity like

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE (teachingID <> 70 OR teachingID IS NULL) 
AND typeID = 22
```

Or, simply use null coalescing function `COALESCE()` like

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE COALESCE(teachingID,0) <> 70 
AND typeID = 22
```

Answer (score 0):

As you should now know, NULL is different from any value.  In SQL you can check it's value using ISNULL (eg. WHERE teachingID IS NULL).  Of course you could use COALESCE() function as someone suggested above.

If you want all the teachingId <>70 OR = NULL with a certain typeID you can use (be careful with precedence AND / OR and use of brackets, but I thing you should now since it's similar in most programming languages):

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE (teachingID=70 OR teachingID IS NULL) AND typeID= 22;
```